# Device Token is not Generating in parse?

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform

I am using parse push for sending notification 
When i am running my app from different mobile for some mobile push is working but for some push is not working when i seen my parse dashboard there devicetoken for those mob. is not generating and devicetoken is generating for those mob in which push is working.

Code for saving device in parse

```
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().put("UserId", MainSingleTon.ObjectID);

ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

    @Override
        public void done(ParseException arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(arg0==null) { //if Error is null
                Intent loginIntent = new Intent("com.example.welcome.MainActivity");
                MainSingleTon.UniqueId=ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getInstallationId();
                System.out.println("dhawdudiwhdh "+ MainSingleTon.UniqueId);
                startActivity(loginIntent);
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                //saving crendential to shared preferences
                saveCendential(user, password,MainSingleTon.ObjectID);
                // Dismiss Dialog

                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.left_out);
            }
            else {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                showToast(arg0.toString());
            }

        }
});
```

parse data base image link http://screencast.com/t/EdRnu2skfwy3